# Accessing Array from repeat in Polymer

Tags: arrays, polymer

If you have a template-repeat tag like this:

```
<template id="t" repeat="{{i in outputFields}}">
  {{i.name}}
  <template ref="t" repeat="{{i in i.childOutputFields }}"></template>
</template>
```

I would like to be able to acccess the current array in which the template is iterating over so I can add something like this:

```
  <template if="{{i != currentArray[currentArray.length-1] }}">
  ,</template>
```

where currentArray is the array the template is currently iterating over.

Is there a way to get the array that is currently being iterated over?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the inner template with ref="t"?

ref= is used to include templates by reference. So here, you're trying to include the template inside itself. Which is probably not the goal.

Comment: @DocDude Yep, that is exactly the goal.  The general idea is to use recursion to add nodes for a tree data structure.  A general example is given in the Polymer examples: [example](https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/blob/master/examples/how_to/recursive_templates.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I would post what I'm doing here to get around this.  I'm using CSS instead of trying to use the array from the template repeat to determine where to put the comma.

```
#jsonOutputs ul li:after {
  content: " , "; 
}

#jsonOutputs ul li:last-of-type:after {
  content: ""; 
}
```

So instead of trying to access the array or guess which array is currently being iterated over, just use CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Polymer supports array indexing in the template repeat like so:

```
<template repeat="{{item, i in items}}">
  {{item}}<span hidden?="{{i == items.length - 1}}">,</span>
</template>
```

http://jsbin.com/pagejoga/1/edit

Comment: In the case of the example above, it's unknown if the array that is iterating over currently is outputFields or childOutputFields.